# HttpDeleteAttribute doesn't work

Tags: c#, html, http, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

In my controller I tried something like that:

```
    [HttpDelete, ActionName("Delete")]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult DeleteConfirmed(int id)
    {
        Movie movie = db.Movies.Find(id);
        db.Movies.Remove(movie);
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
```

After clicking, steering doesn't visit the method above.
If there is something missing? Maybe the problem is in the view with html code. I am using standard form such as:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    <p>
        <input type="submit" value="Delete" formmethod="delete"/> |
        @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
    </p>
}
```

I tried also `Html.BeginForm("Delete", "Action", FormMethod.Delete)` but it isn't supported by IntelliSense (it shows that there are only FormMethod.Get and FormMethod.Post).

As far as I know, the Delete method is using exactly to manipulate objects to remove from database. Could you explain me if I am right? If not - why? If yes - tell me, please, how to implement that method good way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think it's necessary to restrict your action to `HttpDelete` for your scenario. Use `HttpPost` instead and everything will work just fine.

In case you decide to use that method, then your form should use `HttpDelete` to send the request to the server.

`HttpDelete` is more suitable for a REST Api, I don't see you would get a benefit with that restriction in your case.

Comment: I know, it is in standard MVC4 generated by scaffolding system, but I am interested in how to correctly use the HttpDelete method in MVC4.

Comment: @pt12lol: if it's just for testing purposes you could use RGraham solution but take into account that you're probably making things more complex than necessary.

Answer (score 3):

Add a [HttpMethodOverride](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee407388%28v=vs.108%29.aspx) to your `BeginForm()` call:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
    @Html.HttpMethodOverride(HttpVerbs.Delete)
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    <p>
        <input type="submit" value="Delete" formmethod="delete"/> |
        @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
    </p>
}
```